# POST method on UiPath Orchestrator works from API test application but not from Powershell

Tags: powershell, http, post, uipath

I am developing Powershell scripts to perform functions in UiPath Orchestrator via it's API using `Invoke-WebRequest`/`Invoke-RESTMethod`. The request works in an API test application but not in Powershell.

I am able to successfully generate an authentication bearer key via `Invoke-RestMethod`, but other functions of the API do not work.

```
$auth = @{
   tenancyName = ''
   usernameOrEmailAddress = '****'
   password = '****
}

$authjson = $auth | ConvertTo-Json
$authkey = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://****************.com/api/Account/Authenticate' -Method Post -Body $authjson -ContentType 'application/json'
$authjson = $authkey | ConvertTo-Json

return $authjson
```

This script works and returns the bearer key required for authenticating other requests.

```
$job = @{
    startInfo = {
        ReleaseKey = "efb58582-fcd1-4453-ab0b-d39e1be57392"
        Strategy = "All"
        RobotIds = []
        NoOfRobots = "0"
        JobsCount = "0"
        Source = "Manual"
        InputArguments = "" }
}

$jobjson = $job | ConvertTo-Json

$headers = @{}
$headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer *bearer key here*")

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://**************.com/odata/Jobs/UiPath.Server.Configuration.OData.StartJobs' -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $jobjson  -ContentType application/json
return $response | ConvertTo-Json
```

This script should use the bearer key from the previous authentication script to start a job on UiPath Orchestrator, but it returns this error message:

> Invoke-WebRequest : {"message":"Does not support untyped value in
>   non-open  type.","errorCode":0,"resourceIds":null} At
>   C:\Users\adavenport\Documents\UiPath\warehousejournaltest\apiAuthTest3.ps1:17
>   char:13
>   + $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri '************** ...
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRe     quest],
>   WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebReque
>   stCommand

As far as I can tell, it seems that this error is indicating that the fields in the json body of the request are not correct, but I am copying and pasting it directly from my API test application where it is working correctly, so the fields should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

UiPath Orchestrator now comes with [Swagger](https://swagger.io/). So do login to your Orchestrator and you could make sure that your API call is correct and proper (add `/swagger/ui/index#/` to your URL).
Read more here: https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/v2019-fastTrack/reference